# Why is debugging on vs studio not working properly?

Tags: java, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Whenever I click on debug , it's not pointing to the breakline and program is not stopping.How do I fix this problem?Thanks.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SIUR.png)

Comment: Have you tried placing a breakpoint on a statement instead of a method header?

Comment: How to do that.....?

Comment: IDEs usually allow you to add or remove breakpoints by clicking near where the line numbers are - the column where your break point is on line 2. Try clicking that red dot to remove the break point and clicking the same column on line 3. If you run in debug mode, it should stop at `int a`, allowing you to step through the code line by line. Just an opinion, but I'd recommend initializing `a` and `b` on the line they're declared with a preference to initialize/declare variables closest to where they're used (as in `int c = a + b;`).

Comment: Are you running the application in `Debug` mode ?

Comment: Try following this guide and tell me if it helps https://youtu.be/6cOsxaNC06c

Comment: Can you record a gif to show how you debug?